# Select how many times an item is in the 'in' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the below image taken from SQL Server Management Studio I want to display how many times the number appears in the 'in' clause.

This is the ideal result:

```
internalid  |  contactmethod  |  count
---------------------------------------
113         |  0              |  2    -- 113 appears 2 times in the 'in' clause
142         |  0              |  1    -- 142 appears 1 time in the 'in' clause
150         |  4              |  3    -- 150 appears 3 times in the 'in' clause
```

This is the current situation:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `table valued constructor` and `Left Join`

```
SELECT tc.internalid, 
       b.contactmethod, 
       Count(tc.internalid) 
FROM   (VALUES (150),(150),(150),(113),(113),(142)) tc(internalid) 
       LEFT JOIN Bp_contactmethod(3) b 
              ON tc.internalid = b.internalid 
GROUP  BY tc.internalid, 
          b.contactmethod
```